# Set Gmail to reply text-only to only a specific address

Tags: gmail, text

I just subscribed to a mailing list that (still) requests that messages sent to it be text-only, no exceptions. (Their FAQ references storage space being at a premium on PDAs such as *Palm Pilots*.)

Sooner or later, I'll probably forget to do this, assuming I'm setting this for each message. Is it possible to set up Gmail to automatically default to text-only when composing or replying to a specific listserv?

Comment: Why not just add another google account set to text only?  They have multi-login now.

Comment: So I'd have to use an entire separate account for one mailing list? That seems like it would work but it would be overkill to an *amazing* degree.